# Laravel 6 many to many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

In laravel 6, I have 2 models

```
class Teacher {

}

class Students {

}
```

I have third model to join tables

```
class TeacherStudent {

}
```

Now how can I get all the teachers those are not subscribed by a particular student?

**For example:**
Teacher1, Teacher2, Teacher3, Teacher4 are in the **Teacher** table
and 
Student1, Student2, Student3, Student4 are in the **Student** table

Student1 subscribed Teacher1, Teacher2
Student2 subscribed Teacher1, Teacher4
Student3 subscribed Teacher2

Here, as logedin as **Student1** when I want to see unsubscribed teachers, I should get **Teacher3 and Teacher4**
as logedin as **Student4** when I want to see unsubscribed teachers, I should get **all teachers** and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you've defined all relations in your models

```
// in your controller
$user = auth()->user();

// where 'students' is a many-to-many relationship you have in you Teacher model
$teachers = Teacher::whereDoesntHave('students', function($query) use($user) {
    return  $query
          ->where('user_id', $user->id);
});
```

The above query will retrieve all teachers that don't belong to current authenticated user.

In case you haven't defined any relation in your models. They should look something like this:

```
// Teacher model
public function students() {
  // many to many relationship
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Student', 'subscriber'); // replace subscribers with your pivot table
}
```

An the student model:

```
// Student model
public function teachers() {
   // many to many relationship
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Teacher', 'subscriber'); // replace subscribers with your pivot table
}
```

PS: haven't tested any of that, let me know if they don't work